# Standalone Output Directory

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, standalone, auxiliary-files, output

I configured my `TexStudio` to use a Directory for temporary files called "build".

When i compile the standalone document all files except the `pdf` and the `synctex.gz` are in the folder "build". When I compile the Main Document all temporary files of the main document are in the build folder, but the standalone files will clutter my base directory.

Is there a way to prevent this?

For clarification the folder structure looks like that:

- BaseFolder/

  - Document.tex
  - Standalone.tex
  - Build/

After compilation it looks like that:

- BaseFolder/

  - Document.tex
  - Standalone.tex
  - Document.pdf
  - Standalone.pdf
  - Document.synctex.gz
  - Standalone.aux
  - Standalone.log
  - Standalone.aux
  - Build/

    - Document.aux
    - Document.log
    - Document.auxlock

Document contains:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{mode=buildnew}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    this is a Document.
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
    \centering
    \includestandalone{Standalone}
    \caption{The caption text}\label{fig:abc}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Standalone contains:

```
\documentclass[convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[blue, mark=x] coordinates {(0,0)
    (1,2)(2,3)
    (3,4)(4,6)
    (5,11)(6,20)
    (7,15)(8,12)
    (9,8)(10,7)
    (11,3)(12,0)};
\label{axis1}
\end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is being addressed by the maintainer: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/34/using-the-pdflatex-build-dir-option-with